# Spark computing variance over a window

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, window-functions

i have a dataframe structured as follows:

```
+------------------+
|   id  |     value|
+------------------+
|  user0|     100  |
|  user1|     102  |
|  user0|     109  |
|  user2|     103  |
|  user1|     108  |
|  user0|     119  |
|  user0|     140  |
|  user0|     142  |
+------------------+
```

I would like to compute the variance between each row and the preceeding for each ID, for this purpose i tried the following code:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

w_vv = Window.partitionBy('id')  
df=df.withColumn('variances',F.round(F.var_pop("value"),2).over(w_vv.rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding,0)))
```

this is the ideal desired output

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
|   User|  value|                                     variances|
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
|  user0| value1|         -                                    |
|  user1| value1|         -                                    |
|  user0| value2|  variance(value2,value1)                     |
|  user1| value2|  variance(value2,value1)                     |
|  user1| value3|  variance(value3,value2,value1)              |
|  user0| value3|  variance(value4,value3,value2,value1)       |
|  user0| value4|  variance(value4,value3,value2,value1)       |
|  user0| value5|  variance(value5,value4,value3,value2,value1)|
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
```

the previous output with numbers as an example:

```
+---------------------------+
|   User|  value|  variances|
+---------------------------+
|  user0| 2|         -      |
|  user1| 4|         -      |
|  user0| 3| 0.25           |
|  user1| 3| 0.25           |
|  user1| 9| 6.9            |
|  user0| 7| 4.7            |
|  user0| 3| 3.7            |     
|  user0| 4| 3              |
+---------------------------+
```

however the code returns the following error

```
grouping expressions sequence is empty, and '`timestamp`' is not an aggregate function.  
Wrap '(var_pop(CAST(`value` AS DOUBLE)) AS `_w0`)' in windowing function(s) or wrap  
'`timestamp`' in first() (or first_value) if you don't care which value you get.;;
```

I understand aggregate functions should be used over groupBy but i don't know how to code it so it works, any ideas? thanks

Comment: can you add numerical outcome expectation?

Comment: @thebluephantom sure, done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should attach the window to `var_pop`, not `round`:

```
w_vv = Window.partitionBy('id')  

df = df.withColumn('variances',
    F.round(
        F.var_pop("value")
         .over(w_vv.rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding,0)
    , 2)
)
```